# Jenkins with Copy Artifact plugin

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to copy the artifacts from an upstream job using the "Copy Artifact" Jenkins plugin but I'm getting this error message:

Failed to copy [upstream_dir]\Generated_Code\XX.XX.g.cs to [downstream_dir]\XX.XX.g.cs due to java.io.FileNotFoundException [downstream_dir]\Generated_Code\XX.XX.g.cs (Access is denied)

It occurs only while trying to copy this file, which is auto generated by WCF RIA Services.

I'm using the "Upstream build that triggered this job" option for the "Which build" setting, copying all artifacts by using the "**" wildcards.

Jenkins: ver. 1.436
Copy Artifact Plugin: ver. 1.19

Comment: Can you download that artifact manually from the upstream job?

Comment: Yes, If I copy the artifact in Windows Explorer no one error is fired.

Comment: Sounds weird. Create an Ticket (http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) May be you have more luck with an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months...

I decided to by pass the death star (@BlessedGeek reference) locking schema, so this bat file runs before all other steps:

```
ECHO OFF
CLS

ECHO Perfect Unlock application to avoid Ria Services locking errors
ECHO.
ECHO STATUS: 
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Jenkins....\Generated_Code\MyApp.WebServices.g.cs" GOTO NOWINDIR

attrib -r "C:\Jenkins....\Generated_Code\MyApp.WebServices.g.cs" /d /s
ECHO Sucess!
ECHO.
EXIT 0

:NOWINDIR
ECHO At first build there is no folder or file to unlock.
ECHO.
EXIT 0
```

Comment: This is not black magic. This is death star, because it won't work on Linux. Because the death star promotes monopoly to one particularly detestable platform. Black magic = hidden powerful features.

Answer (score 2):

To copy all artifacts using the plugin, you should leave the `Artifacts to copy` field **blank**. [See help options for "Artifacts to copy" by clicking the `?` near the field for more information]

For Jenkins plugins, "**" (double asterisk) normally refers to workspace, not to a "select all" wildcard.

Hope that helps..